# How to use string.format with nested dict

Tags: python

I have a nested dict:

```
KEYS1 = ("A", "B", "C")
KEYS2 = ("X", "Y", "Z")

d = dict.fromkeys(KEYS1, dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0))
```

I'd now like to embed its values in a string using format, something like

```
print("d['A']['X']={A,X:d}".format(**d))
```

to output:

```
d['A']['X']=0
```

That does not work. Any suggestions on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more the expected output?

Comment: `d = dict.fromkeys(KEYS1, dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0))` - watch out. Every value in the outer dict is the *same* inner dict, so anything you do to `d['A']` will be visible through `d['B']`.

Comment: Oh, you're right user2357112 - thanks for catching this. What would you suggest for instantiation of 2 dim storage with keys to zeros?

Comment: @Oxonon: Dict comprehension, or `dict` with a genexp in Python <2.7. `{key1: dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0) for key1 in KEYS1}`, or `dict((key1, dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0)) for key1 in KEYS1)`. In cases where the inner values also need to be distinct, you can replace the inner `fromkeys` with a dict comprehension too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
KEYS1 = ("A", "B", "C")
KEYS2 = ("X", "Y", "Z")

d = dict.fromkeys(KEYS1, dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0))

print("d['A']['X']={A[X]}".format(**d))
```

Output:

```
d['A']['X']=0
```

From python 3.6 you will be able to access the dict in the string use [Literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
In [23]: print(f"d['A']['X']={d['A']['X']}")
d['A']['X']=0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of `str.format`'s ability to do subscripting on the arguments you provide.

```
KEYS1 = ("A", "B", "C")
KEYS2 = ("X", "Y", "Z")

d = dict.fromkeys(KEYS1, dict.fromkeys(KEYS2, 0))

print("d['A']['X']={[A][X]}".format(d))
```

This is really similar to [Padraic Cunningham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34442605/1612701), which is also a good and correct way to do it (which is why I +1'd it).  The difference is that in his answer, the part of the string `{A[X]}` means that the `.format` method is looking for a keyword argument, which gets provided by unpacking the dict `d`.

In my method, it is expecting a positional argument, which must be a dict with a key `'A'`, which must also be a dict with the key `'X'`