# str.format() with nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, string.format

I want to use the str.format() method like this:

```
my_str = "Username: {username}, User data: {user_data.attribute}".format(**items)
```

And apply it to items as shown below:

```
items = {
    "username" : "Peter",
    "user_data" : {
         "attribute" : "foo"
    }}
```

Is this feasible, and if so, then how? If not, I'm interested in your recommended approach.

Comment: (you don't need to have `Python` in the title, the tag [tag:python] automatically append "python" to the title)

Comment: @user202729 It does append the first tag to the title of the webpage (<TITLE> here </TITLE>) but doesn't append it the title of the question

Comment: [Exact dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442448/how-to-use-string-format-with-nested-dict).

Comment: @Psytho But still, it's not encouraged to tag in the title. [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: ... votes are weird. Sometimes dupes are downvoted and sometimes they are upvoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use string.format with nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442448/how-to-use-string-format-with-nested-dict)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
items = {'username': 'Peter', 'user_data': {'attribute': 'foo'}}

my_str = "Username: {username}, User data: {user_data[attribute]}".format(**items)

>>> my_str
'Username: Peter, User data: foo'
```

Comment: Huh. That works. I didn't expect it to be that easy, many thanks! I hope the question will be helpful to somebody else.

Comment: @Konrad It was =)